# globbing dataframes or other objects in R

Tags: r, object, glob

This should be a simple one, i hope. I have several dataframes loaded into workspace, labelled df01 to df100, not all numbers represented. I'd like to plot a specific column across all datasets, for example in a box plot. How do I refer all objects starting with df, using globbing, ie:

```
boxplot(df00$col1, df02$col1, df04$col1)

 = 

boxplot(df*$col1)
```

Comment: some numbers can be missing? like `df71` can be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
nums      <- sprintf("%02d", 0:100)
dfs.names <- Filter(exists, paste0("df", nums))
dfs.obj   <- lapply(dfs.names, get)
dfs.col1  <- lapply(dfs.obj, `[[`, "col1")

do.call(boxplot, dfs.col1)
```

Comment: I think df.cols1 should be the x argument to boxplot, so do.call isn't required

Comment: Thank you, flodel. I didn't know about Filter before - have to try this out! Best wishes!

Comment: flawless! Now I'll just have to spend some time understanding it :-)

Answer (score 5):

The idomatic approach is to work with lists, or to use a separate environment.

You can create this list using `ls` and `pattern`

```
df.names <- ls(pattern = '^df')
# note 
# ls(pattern ='^df[[:digit:]]{2,}')
# may be safer if there are objects starting with df you don't want

df.list <- mget(df.names)
# note if you are using a version of R prior to R 3.0.0
# you will need `envir = parent.frame()`
# mget(ls(pattern = 'df'), envir = parent.frame()) 

# use `lapply` to extract the relevant columns

df.col1 <- lapply(df.list, '[[', 'col1')

# call boxplot   

boxplot(df.col1)
```

Comment: Thank you, mnel - this is very useful, especially with the commenting! Very happy! Best wishes!

Comment: Error in mget(df.names) : argument "envir" is missing, with no default

Comment: @Stefan -- mget has a default argument from `R 3.0.0` onwards. Use `mget(ls(pattern = 'df'), envir = parent.frame())` for previous version of R

Comment: thank you, I got passed that, but still get an error on the next step:df.sR <- lapply(df.list, '[[', 's.R')
Error in FUN(X[[2L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: try `lapply(df.list, function(x) x[['s.R']])` -- are you sure this column exists in all the data.frames?

Comment: Yes, with @flodel 's method below it plotted all 24 boxes I was expecting. with 'lapply(df.list, function(x) x[['s.R']])' I still get: Error in x[["s.R"]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @Stefan, try with the alternative `df.names  <- ls(pattern ='^df[[:digit:]]{2,}'); df.list <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df'), envir = parent.frame())`

Comment: thank you, but even with the new df.names, I still get out of bounds errors with both the original and new lapply. Sorry have asked you to troubleshoot without a sample of the data. I'm wondering whether part of the problem is that some values are "NA"...

Comment: If you are running @flodels solution and getting it to work, look at `setdiff(df.names, dfs.names)`

Comment: `setdiff(df.names, dfs.names)` results in `character(0)`

Comment: and `setdiff(dfs.names, df.names)`?

Comment: any idea why this doesn't work? (i know I'm such a newbie): `tabname<-"$s.R"; dfs.tabnames<-gsub(" ","", paste(df.names,tabname) , fixed=TRUE); boxplot(c(dfs.tabnames))` How do I tell boxplot to interpret dfs.tabnames as objects?

Comment: Yes. That is not how R works. a character string is a character string, and isn't interpreted as language.